# Sequencing a StateMonad in Cats

Tags: scala, state-monad, scala-cats

I just had a look into the cats library in scala, more specifically the State Monad.

As a toy example I wanted to create some logic that splits a potentially large string (the StringBuilder) and returns the split up String and the remaining StringBuilder:

```scala
object Splitter {
  def apply(maxSize: Int, overlap: Int): State[StringBuilder, String] = State(
    builder => {
      val splitPoint = math.min(builder.size, maxSize + overlap)
      (builder.drop(maxSize), builder.substring(0, splitPoint))
    }
  )
}
```

Running one step of the State monad works fine but I wanted to chain all the steps until the StringBuilder eventually is empty:

```scala
val stop = State.inspect((s: StringBuilder) => s.isEmpty)
Splitter(3, 2).untilM[Vector](stop).run(new StringBuilder("tarsntiars"))
```

However, this doesn't work as untilM is a member of the Monad trait and there are no implicit conversions in scope. What works is:

```scala
val monad = StateT.catsDataMonadForStateT[Eval, StringBuilder]
monad.untilM[List, String](Splitter(3, 2))(stop).run(new StringBuilder("tarsntiars"))
```

However, I think the shorter is much more readable so I am wondering why it doesn't work? Why does the usual MonadOps mechanism doesn't work here?

Comment: what is "stop"?

Comment: I added the definition of stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After SI-2712 was fixed, the `Unapply` workaround was removed from Cats: https://github.com/typelevel/cats/pull/1583. Now you need the `-Ypartial-unification` compiler flag (assuming you are using Scala 2.11 or 2.12) in order for `State` to be treated as a `Monad`.

Scalaz still has the `Unapply` machinery so your code should work with Scalaz without the compiler flag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As it this is the accepted answer, I'd like to add that this breaks syntax highlighting in IntelliJ IDEA. They are aware of it and it will be fixed with: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11320

Comment: it's worth noting that if you're using a version of Scala 2.11 before 2.11.9 or even Scala 2.10 you can still use this sbt plugin to enable the partial unification fix: https://github.com/fiadliel/sbt-partial-unification (bonus: if you're using a supported version the plugin will just enable the flag)